# Angular2:getting event.target.value

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to get `event.target.value` by the codes below.

```
    <input 
      mdInput 
      #owner
      required 
      placeholder="荷主" 
      [formControl]="detail.ownerTx" 
      [mdAutocomplete]="autoTxt" 
      (change)="detail.changeOwner(owner.value)"
     >

   class Detail {
    changeOwner(val: string){
     console.log(val);
    }
   }
```

but the answer of the `console.log(val)` is nothing.... any idea to actually do the data-binding??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should use (keyup) or another keyboard event handler if you want to get this value using (keyup)="changeInput($event)" then you can access you DOM event and value ;)

Answer (score 5):

```
(input)="detail.changeOwner($event.target.value)"
```

or

```
ngModel (ngModelChange)="detail.changOwner($event)"
```

You can also subscribe to `valueChanges` on the form control (`detail.ownerTx`)
See also https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#valueChanges

Comment: What would it not work? And what does "not work" mean exactly?

Comment: right,

`console.log("val:" + val)` in class Detail anwsered `val:`.

nothing is in it.

Comment: I updated my answer. See also https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vix2nq

Comment: Thank you so much for the advises and even example,but somehow (input) doesn't let console show the value. I think its related to `mdAutocomplete`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean with "doesn't let console show the value". It's printed to the console in my stackblitz

Comment: and (keyup)  actually works well and console shows the value, so I think I wanna go that way.....

Comment: sorry for my English. `console.log("val:" + val)`  in class Detail anwsered  `val:`. still empty....

Comment: It prints the value in the stackblitz I posted above in Chrome.

Comment: yeah, I saw your the stackblitz too. I assume `formcontrol` or `md-Autocomplete` related to this problems.

Comment: Don't know these. It's possible I guess.

Answer (score 1):

change the input line to this

```
<input 
      mdInput 
      #owner
      required 
      placeholder="荷主" 
      [formControl]="detail.ownerTx" 
      [mdAutocomplete]="autoTxt" 
      (change)="detail.changeOwner($event)">
```

and function to this :

```
class Detail {
    changeOwner($event){
     //You will get the target with bunch of other options as well.  
     console.log($event.target.value);
    }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a component method to implement the cast, it is not possible to cast in templates!

```
@Component({
  selector: '...',
  template: '<input (keyup)="filter(target($event).value)">',
})
export class SomeCmp {
  target(event: KeyboardEvent): HTMLInputElement {
    if (!(event.target instanceof HTMLInputElement)) {
      throw new Error("wrong target");
    }
    return event.target;
  }
}
```

Also see https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35293

Answer (score 0):

What I did and worked for me (with angular 15) is like bellow:

In HTML File

```
<input matInput type="text" (keyup)="doFilter($event)" placeholder="filter">
```

Inside the component:

```
doFilter(filterValue?: Event) { 
      console.log("Filter: ", (filterValue?.target as HTMLInputElement).value);
      if((filterValue?.target as HTMLInputElement).value != null) {
        this.dataSource.filter = (filterValue?.target as HTMLInputElement).value.trim().toLowerCase();
      }
    }
```

I hope it will help someone :)

Happy coding!