# Angular 6 - text field change event has no data

Tags: javascript, angular6

I am developing new page in angular 6 application. I am trying to get the value of the current input from the 'change' event will be triggered.

**My issue is that:** The change event of an input has no data it just has "isTrusted" parameter !

Off-course when i am trying to get any other parameter (i.e. event.value, event.target ...etc.) it is giving me undefined.

**Component HTML template & function :**

```
 <div *ngFor="let items of item>
      <input type="text" id="{{item.id}}" (change)="dummyFunc($event)">
</div>
```

=======

```
dummyFunc(eve){
  console.log("dummy change .. "+JSON.stringify(eve));
}
```

output from dummyFunc is :

> dummy change .. {"isTrusted":true}

I have used change and input events but it is giving me the same result. does $event object contains only  "isTrusted" and doesn't have any other details or i did something wrong ?

Comment: You need to use `eve.target.value` since you are using `(change)`

Comment: @HarunYilmaz .. yes it works !
But how come it is not printed when i called JSON.stringify ??

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41020307/why-does-json-stringify-only-show-the-istrusted-member-of-a-click-event

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular2:getting event.target.value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152847/angular2getting-event-target-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `$event.target.value`

Like this:

```
 <div *ngFor="let items of item>
      <input type="text" id="{{item.id}}" (change)="dummyFunc($event.target.value)">
</div>
```